# solr.RandomSortField on multiple solr server instances

Tags: sorting, random, solr, field

Got a solr question here, I have multiple solr server instances they all the same data and schema, the schema contains a dynamic field which is `solr.RandomSortField`, so I am wondering if I run `sort=rand_1234%20desc` on different solr servers, am I suppose to get the same result?

Comment: why not try it :-) But I doubt that you'll get the same ... in order to achive that all solr instances would have to have the same random see when creating new Random(seed)

Comment: @Karussell, yes I am make sure the seeds are the same, however I cannot test on production system(the only environment has multiple instances) because it commits changes all the time, so the result won't be the same.

Comment: But then you'll have different results even for normal results!? You should make sure that the new searchers will be opened at the same time (e.g. with replication or with a separate read only core)

Comment: see http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication and http://wiki.apache.org/solr/NearRealtimeSearchTuning

Comment: @karussell I just realised the replication is not going to fix my issue... our solr database is constantly being updated and committed, therefore while the user on page 2 of the search result, a few commits could have happened, and then page 3 is different result set again.

Comment: does adding a date filter (to every request) help? e.g. if its a twitter like app all docs have a date included ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the source code of RandomSortField, the seed includes the version number of the index. This means that if you issue a search with the same random parameter (e.g. "sort=random_1234") on different servers the same result is returned if the indexes are equal (same content) and have the same version id (via replication).

You can check the version of the indexes in the /admin/ ui of every server.

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.solr/solr-core/3.5.0/org/apache/solr/schema/RandomSortField.java

Comment: Note that in some cases, the versions of the indexes can be frequently out of sync across servers.