# Sort by constant number

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I need to randomize Solr (6.6.2) search results, but the order needs to be consistent given a specific seed. This is for a paginated search that returns a limited result set from a much larger one, so I must do the ordering at the query level and not at the application level once the data has been fetched.

Initially I tried this:

```
https://localhost:8984/solr/some_index/select?q=*:*&sort=random_999+ASC
```

Where `999` is a constant that is fed in when constructing the query prior to sending it to Solr. The constant value changes for each new search.

This solution works. However, when I run the query a few times, or run it on different Solr instances, the ordering is different.

After doing some reading, `random_` generates a number via:

```
fieldName.hashCode() + context.docBase + (int)top.getVersion()
```

This means that when the random number is generated, it takes the index version into account. This becomes problematic when using a distributed architecture or when indexes are updated, as is well explained [here](https://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Random-sorting-and-result-consistency-across-successive-calls-based-on-seed-td4170508.html).

There are various recommended solutions online, but I am trying to avoid writing a custom `random` override. Is there some type of trick where I can feed in some type of function or equation to the `sort` param?

For example:

`min(999,random_999)`

Though this always results in the same order, even when either of the values change.

This question is somewhat similar to this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600174/solr-randomsortfield-on-multiple-solr-server-instances?rq=1), but not quite.

I searched for answers on SO containing `solr.RandomSortField`, and while they point out what the issue is, none of them have a solution. It seems the best way would be to override the `solr.RandomSortField` logic, but it's not clear how.

**Prior Research**

- https://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Random-sorting-and-result-consistency-across-successive-calls-based-on-seed-td4170508.html
- [Solr: Random sort order after index version change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35126396/solr-random-sort-order-after-index-version-change)
- https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-dev/201811.mbox/%3CJIRA.13196983.1541639245000.300557.1541639520069@Atlassian.JIRA%3E
- [Solr - Return random results (Sort by Random)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234102/solr-return-random-results-sort-by-random/25252121)
- https://realize.be/blog/random-results-apache-solr-and-drupal
- https://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Sorting-with-customized-function-of-score-td3987281.html

Comment: Why can't you sort based on score ?

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti We can't sort on score alone because that would result in fixed ordering for searches with the same parameters. We need the results to be "shuffled" in a predictable fashion using a seed number. Sorting based on score would work if we could perform some type of mathematical operation on it (multiply / divide / etc) with a specified constant number. I have tried such options, but haven't yet been able to figure out the required syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even after implementing a custom random sort field, the results still differed across instances of Solr.

I ended up adding a new field that is populated at index time which is a 32 bit hash of an ID field that already existed in the document.

I then built a "stateless" linear congruential generator to produce a set of acceptably random numbers to use for sorting:

`?sort=mod(product(hash_int_id,{seedConstant},982451653), 104395301) asc`

Since this function technically passes a new seed for each row, and because it does not store state (like `rand.Next()` would), this solution is admittedly inferior and it is not a true PRNG; however, it does seem to get me most of the way there. Note that you will have to tune your values depending on the size of your data set and the size of the values in your `hash_int_id` equivalent field.